# How do I install the latest version of Matlab?

Tags: 13.04, software-center, matlab

When I tried to install Matlab using the Software Center, it prompted me for the `Location of MATLAB installation(s)`. Since I am trying to install it, I don't know what to do.

[image]

Comment: Here is at least 'the latest' version tutorial. https://karibe.co.ke/2018/11/installing-matlab-2018a-from-two-iso-images-in-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to install `matlab-support`, which needs matlab to be installed first. Follow the instructions given here to install matlab first:

- [Installing Matlab on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB)

In the instructions given on that page, when you try to install the "ia32-libs" package, you will be prompted to choose an application. For this click on "browse" and then go to **/usr/bin/software-center**.

Answer (score 1):

**MATLAB** in the software centre does not provide [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/programs/nrd/matlab-trial-request.html?ref=ggl&s_eid=ppc_4771) which is not free but helps to configure an existing MATLAB installation to run better on Debian based Linux operating systems such as Ubuntu as shown below.

[image]

If you are looking for similar free programs for Ubuntu take a look at this question:
[Similar tools for MATLAB](https://askubuntu.com/q/297304/107450)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I assume that you have **MatlabR201x.iso** for Linux.

Make directory under /media/'username'/iso with sudo. here is example for username da.

```
sudo mkdir /home/da/iso
```

Then mount the Matlab installation .iso to that directory.

```
mount MatlabR201x.iso /home/da/iso -o loop
```

then execute the installer with sudo permissions.

```
sudo /medida/da/bin/install
```

That's it.

Ps: These instructions are tested with latest Kubuntu 19.10 in time of writing.