# Matlab 2014 student version hangs when hangs on splash screen

Tags: matlab

As the title says, I've currently installed matlab2014a (Student) and now when I go to launch it it just hangs on the splash screen.

> /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin$ ./matlab

I've checked System Monitor and every time, after about 6~seconds, the process just goes to sleep.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

OK I managed to fix it! : See my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the latest version of Matlab?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/349144/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling around for awhile I managed to get the answer!

If you installed with appropriate root access (i.e `gksu ./install` or `root ./install`) and your Matlab is hanging then it is a permissions issue.

The most likely culprit, as it was for me, is that MatLab is trying to write the license to a previous root directory even after a fresh install.

In my previous install I was messing around with `chown` to give permissions to read/write after not installing with `sudo` or `gksu`. Although Matlab started to acknowledge some of it (i. e. stop spitting out an error when I activated it), it still interacted poorly (the hanging).

Make sure when you remove MatLab you don't just remove the files from `/usr/...`, but also the files in `~/.matlab`. Just `cd` to the directory, move up one, and remove it with with `rm -rf`.

After that do a fresh install and it should work fine.

Note: I have the student license.