# MATLAB install error: Failed to create folder

Tags: software-installation, matlab

I'm trying to install MATLAB R2015b on Ubuntu 15.10 via an iso installer, but when I get to the 'Choose Installation Folder' stage and click next, I get an error message:

```
Failed to Create Folder (/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/)
```

The default folder is set to `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b` and I have tried others (`/opt/` and `/usr/local/bin/`) but get the same error message. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I have also tried rerunning the installer via:

```
sudo ./install
```

but just get the `command not found` error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the latest version of Matlab?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/349144/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-matlab)

Answer (score 4):

> When matlab installation folder selection window appears erase all the text in the text box and put `/home/Your_user_name/Matlab` and continue . (the default path is `/usr/local/Matlab/Rxxx`, don't use it)

From https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1493 .