# Error during installing matlab-support

Tags: dpkg, matlab

While installing matlab-support,I get following error message.

```
No default Matlab path found. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package matlab-support (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 matlab-support
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the latest version of Matlab?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/349144/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

`matlab-support` is described (via `apt-cache search matlab-support`) as:

```
matlab-support - distro integration for local MATLAB installations
```

it is NOT `MATLAB`, it is just the glue between `MATLAB` and your distribution. As the error message says, `No default Matlab path found.`

You will have to install MATLAB (probably, as @David Foerster says, by reading   [How do I install the latest version of Matlab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349144/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-matlab)